# In CSS how to eliminate animation jerkiness and unwanted space created by elements with relative position?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-animations

I've got this "search-box" with several input fields. I'm trying to add a 2nd placeholder element to get that text transformation effect when clicking the search fields e. g. `<span class="placeholder2" >Insert banana number:</span>`. These 2nd additional placeholders created 2 unwanted changes:

1. A trembling/jerkiness in the animation after the search field is clicked to start typing, particularly the 1st search field.
2. An unwanted space between each search field. In the example below I have removed the 2nd place holder of the 2nd search field to see the difference:
    the space between "apples" and "peach" is ok, but between "bananas" and "apples" is not.

I need a way to:

1. Remove the jerkiness from the animation.
2. Remove the unwanted space created by the 2nd placeholder text.

My guess is that the issue is probably the fact that the positioning of the placeholders is set as `position: relative;`. I tried several workarounds/tricks but I cannot get rid of these 2 issues, without messing up the position/size etc. of the search fields and "SEARCH" buttons.

Is there a way to fix this or some workaround?

Example is below:
(also in case you prefer here: https://jsfiddle.net/jqzzy/ztnp0275/19/ )

```js
///////////////////////// - BODY LOAD FIX - ///////////////////////////////

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  document.querySelector("body").classList.add("body_onload");
});

////////////////////////// - ANIMATE ITEMS ON LOAD - ////////////////////////

var items = document.getElementsByClassName("fade-item");
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
  fadeIn(items[i], i * 50)
}

function fadeIn(item, delay) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    item.classList.add('fadein')
  }, delay)
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(26, 26, 26);
  color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
  width: 290px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 1px rgb(78, 78, 78);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


/* ////////////////// ANIMATION ITEMS ONLOAD //////////////// */

.fade-item {
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

.fadein {
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 0.2s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.3);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.0);
  }
}


/* ////////////////// STRUCTURE //////////////////// */

table.unstyledTable thead th {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.special-text {
  color: red;
}

.askit {
  color: red;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 2px;
  font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.title {
  color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 3px;
  font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.sections {
  color: rgb(168, 168, 168);
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 2px;
  font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.footing {
  color: rgb(155, 155, 155);
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 2px;
  font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .topnav a,
  .topnav input[type=text],
  .topnav .search-container button {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  .topnav input[type=text] {
    border: 1px solid rgb(102, 102, 102);
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}


/*////// BUTTON ///////*/

.form-submit-button {
  background: #464646;
  color: rgb(172, 172, 172);
  border-style: solid;
  height: 39px;
  width: 60px;
  font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 0px solid rgb(102, 102, 102);
  border-radius: 9px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease-out;
  animation: 0.25s ease-out 0s 1 scaleBtn;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scaleBtn {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
  }
}

.form-submit-button:hover {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 5px #6461ff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 5px #6461ff;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}

.flex-parent:hover .form-submit-button {
  background: #5c5c5c;
}

.input:hover {
  background: #3d3d3d;
}

s
/*/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}


/*///////////// HIGHLIGHT BOX ANIMATION /////////////// */

span input[type="text"] {
  border: 2px solid rgb(238, 238, 238);
  background-color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
  height: 40px;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0);
  /* will-change: transform, opacity; */
  border: none;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease-out;
  animation: 0.25s ease-out 0s 1 scaleBtn;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scaleBtn {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.65);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
  }
}

span input[type="text"]:focus {
  margin: 3px;
  scale: 103%;
  border-color: #e63f3f;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(233, 102, 102, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(233, 102, 102, 0.6);
}

span input:focus {
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
  margin: 3px;
  scale: 103%;
  border-color: #e63f3f;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(233, 102, 102, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(233, 102, 102, 0.6);
}


/*///////////// PLACEHOLDER TEXT ANIMATION /////////////// */

.placeholder {
  position: relative;
  width: 0px;
  top: -32px;
  right: -5px;
  font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  color: grey;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0);
  pointer-events: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: 1;
}

.input:focus~.placeholder {
  top: -55px;
  right: -8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #e4a8a8;
  opacity: 0;
}

.placeholder2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 0px;
  top: -50px;
  right: 0px;
  font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  color: grey;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0);
  pointer-events: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: 0;
}

.input:focus~.placeholder2 {
  top: -75px;
  right: -8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #e4a8a8;
  background-color: rgb(26, 26, 26);
  opacity: 1;
}

input:not(:focus) {
  top: -60px;
  right: -2px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgba(158, 89, 89, 0);
}


/*////////////////////// DIV ALIGNMENT SIDE BY SIDE ////////////////////////*/

.inline-block-child {
  display: inline-block;
}

.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-child {
  flex: 2 1 auto;
}

.inline-flex-parent {
  display: inline-flex;
}


/*//////////////// TOP NAV  ///////////////// */

#box_active {
  font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #6461ff;
}

.no-underline {
  color: #ababab;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="boxes.css">
  <title>Fruit box v1.0.2</title>

</head>

<body>

  <h4>MY FRUITS</h4>

  <section>
    <span class="fade-item">
        <div class="parent flex-parent">
          <div class="child flex-child">
            <div class="topnav">
              <input type="text" id="linkBananas" class="input" maxlength="" value="" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off">
              <span class="placeholder">Search for bananas:</span>
    <span class="placeholder2">Insert banana number:</span>

    </div>
    </div>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <div class="child flex-child">
      <button id="linkBananas_BT" type="submit" class="form-submit-button" tabindex="-1">SEARCH</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </span>
  </section>

  <!-- /// -->

  <section>
    <span class="fade-item">
        <div class="parent flex-parent">
          <div class="child flex-child">
            <div class="topnav">
              <input type="text" id="linkApples" class="input" maxlength="" value="" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off">
              <span class="placeholder">Search for apples:</span>
    <!--<span class="placeholder2" >Enter apple number:</span> -->
    </div>
    </div>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <div class="child flex-child">
      <button id="linkApples_BT" type="submit" class="form-submit-button" tabindex="-1">SEARCH</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </span>
  </section>

  <!-- /// -->

  <span class="fade-item">
      <div class="parent flex-parent">
        <div class="child flex-child">
          <div class="topnav">
            <input type="text" id="linkPeach" class="input" maxlength="" value="" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off">
            <span class="placeholder">Search for peach:</span>
  <span class="placeholder2">Enter peach number:</span>
  </div>
  </div>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <div class="child flex-child">
    <button id="linkPeach_BT" type="submit" class="form-submit-button" tabindex="-1">SEARCH</button>
  </div>
  </div>
  </span>

  <!-- /// -->

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: inline-grid;` fixed the jerkiness and unwanted space:
( in case you prefer check solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/jqzzy/ztnp0275/115/ )

```js
///////////////////////// - BODY LOAD FIX - ///////////////////////////////

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    document.querySelector("body").classList.add("body_onload");
});

////////////////////////// - ANIMATE ITEMS ON LOAD - ////////////////////////

var items = document.getElementsByClassName("fade-item");
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
    fadeIn(items[i], i * 50)
}
function fadeIn(item, delay) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        item.classList.add('fadein')
    }, delay)
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(26, 26, 26);
    color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
    border: solid 1px rgb(158, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 500px;
    width: 290px;
}



/* ////////////////// ANIMATION ITEMS ONLOAD //////////////// */

.fade-item {
    transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

.fadein {
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation-duration: 0.2s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: scale(0.75);
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: scale(1.0);
    }
}

/* ////////////////// STRUCTURE //////////////////// */

table.unstyledTable thead th {
    font-weight: normal;
}

.special-text {
    color: red;
}

.askit {
    color: red;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 2px;
    font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.title {
    color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 3px;
    font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.sections {
    color: rgb(168, 168, 168);
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 2px;
    font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.footing {
    color: rgb(155, 155, 155);
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 10px;
    padding: 2px;
    font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

    .topnav a,
    .topnav input[type=text],
    .topnav .search-container button {
        float: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
        width: 200px;
        margin: 0px;

    }

    .topnav input[type=text] {
        border: 1px solid rgb(102, 102, 102);
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}

.top-nav {
    position: relative;
}

/*////// BUTTON ///////*/

.form-submit-button {
    background: #464646;
    color: rgb(172, 172, 172);
    border-style: solid;
    height: 39px;
    width: 60px;
    font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    border: 0px solid rgb(102, 102, 102);
    border-radius: 9px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease-out;
    animation: 0.25s ease-out 0s 1 scaleBtn;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scaleBtn {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.5);
    }

    100% {
        transform: scale(1.0);
    }
}

.form-submit-button:hover {
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 5px #6461ff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 5px #6461ff;
    -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease-out;
    display: inline;
}

.flex-parent:hover .form-submit-button {
    background: #5c5c5c;
    display: inline;
}

.input:hover {
    background: #3d3d3d;
    display: inline;
}

s
/*/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

button:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

/*///////////// HIGHLIGHT BOX ANIMATION /////////////// */

span input[type="text"] {
    border: 2px solid rgb(238, 238, 238);
    background-color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
    height: 40px;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0);
    /* will-change: transform, opacity; */
    border: none;
    border: solid 1px #ccc;
    border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease-out;
    animation: 0.25s ease-out 0s 1 scaleBtn;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scaleBtn {
    0% {
        transform: scale(0.65);
    }

    100% {
        transform: scale(1.0);
    }
}

span input[type="text"]:focus {
    margin: 0x;
    scale: 103%;
    border-color: #e63f3f;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(233, 102, 102, 0.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(233, 102, 102, 0.6);
}

span input:focus {
    background-color: #3d3d3d;
    margin: 3px;
    scale: 103%;
    border-color: #e63f3f;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(233, 102, 102, 0.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(233, 102, 102, 0.6);
}

/*///////////// PLACEHOLDER TEXT ANIMATION /////////////// */

.placeholder {
    position: relative;
    width: 0px;
    top: -32px;
    right: -5px;
    font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    color: grey;
    -webkit-transition: 0.25s;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0);
    pointer-events: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    opacity: 1;
}

.input:focus~.placeholder {
    top: -55px;
    right: -8px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #e4a8a8;
    opacity: 0;
}

.placeholder2 {
    position: relative;
    width: 0px;
    top: -50px;
    right: 0px;
    font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    color: grey;
    -webkit-transition: 0.25s;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0);
    pointer-events: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    opacity: 0;
}

.input:focus~.placeholder2 {
    top: -70px;
    right: -8px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #e4a8a8;
    background-color: rgb(26, 26, 26);
    opacity: 1;
}

input:not(:focus) {
    top: -60px;
    right: -2px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: rgba(158, 89, 89, 0);
}

/*////////////////////// DIV ALIGNMENT SIDE BY SIDE ////////////////////////*/

.inline-block-child {
    display: inline-block;
}

.flex-parent {
    display: flex;
}

.flex-child {
    flex: 2 1 auto;
}

.inline-flex-parent {
    display: inline-flex;
}

/*//////////////// TOP NAV  ///////////////// */

#box_active {
    font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #6461ff;
}

.no-underline {
    color: #ababab;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

.grid-container {
    display: inline-grid;
    max-width: 265px;
    max-height: 370px;
    gap: 10px;
    /*background-color: grey;*/
    padding: 0px;
    grid-template-columns: 200px 60px;
    grid-template-rows: 45px 45px 45px 45px 45px 45px 45px 45px 45px 45px 45px 45px;

}

.grid-item {
    /*background-color: purple;*/
    border: none;
}

.item1 {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 1;
}

.item2 {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 1;
}

.item3 {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 2;
}

.item4 {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 2;
}

.item5 {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 3;
}

.item6 {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 3;
}

.item7 {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 4
}

.item8 {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 4
}

.item9 {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 5
}

.item10 {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 5
}

.item11 {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 6;
}

.item12 {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 6
}

.item13 {
    grid-column: 1;
    grid-row: 7;
}

.item14 {
    grid-column: 2;
    grid-row: 7;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="boxes.css">
    <title>Fruit box v1.0.2</title>

  </head>

  <body>

    <h4>MY FRUITS</h4>
<div class="mainContainer">
    <div class="grid-container">

      <!-- /// -->

      <section>
        <span class="fade-item">
          <div class="parent flex-parent">
            <div class="child flex-child">
              <div class="grid-item item1">
                <div class="topnav">
                  <input type="text" id="linkKBs" class="input" maxlength="" value="" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off">
                  <span class="placeholder">Bananas:</span><br/>
                  <span class="placeholder placeholder2">Search Bananas:</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <div class="grid-item item2">
              <div class="child flex-child">
                <button id="linkKBs_BT" type="submit" class="form-submit-button" tabindex="-1">SEARCH</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </span>
      </section><br />

      <!-- /// -->

      <section>
        <span class="fade-item">
          <div class="parent flex-parent">
            <div class="child flex-child">
              <div class="grid-item item3">
                <div class="topnav">
                  <input type="text" id="linkInc" class="input" maxlength="" value="" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off">
                  <span class="placeholder">Oranges:</span><br/>
                  <span class="placeholder placeholder2">Search Oranges:</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <div class="grid-item item4">
              <div class="child flex-child">
                <button id="linkInc_BT" type="submit" class="form-submit-button" tabindex="-1">SEARCH</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </span>
      </section><br />

      <!-- /// -->

      <span class="fade-item">
        <div class="parent flex-parent">
          <div class="child flex-child">
            <div class="grid-item item5">
              <div class="topnav">
                <input type="text" id="linkAAChan" class="input" maxlength="" value="" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off">
                  <span class="placeholder">Peaches:</span><br/>
                  <span class="placeholder placeholder2">Search Peaches:</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <div class="grid-item item6">
            <div class="child flex-child">
              <button id="linkAAChan_BT" type="submit" class="form-submit-button" tabindex="-1">SEARCH</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </span><br />

      <!-- /// -->

      <span class="fade-item">
        <div class="parent flex-parent">
          <div class="child flex-child">
            <div class="grid-item item7">
              <div class="topnav">
                <input type="text" id="linkDirKB" class="input" maxlength="" value="" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off">
                  <span class="placeholder">Papayas:</span><br/>
                  <span class="placeholder placeholder2">Search Papayas:</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <div class="grid-item item8">
            <div class="child flex-child">
              <button id="linkDirKB_BT" type="submit" class="form-submit-button" tabindex="-1">SEARCH</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </span><br />

      <!-- /// -->

      <span class="fade-item">
        <div class="parent flex-parent">
          <div class="child flex-child">
            <div class="grid-item item9">
              <div class="topnav">
                <input type="text" id="linkDirInc" class="input" maxlength="" value="" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off">
                  <span class="placeholder">Pears:</span><br/>
                  <span class="placeholder placeholder2">Search Pears:</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <div class="grid-item item10">
            <div class="child flex-child">
              <button id="linkDirInc_BT" type="submit" class="form-submit-button" tabindex="-1">SEARCH</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </span><br />

      <!-- /// -->

      <span class="fade-item">
        <div class="parent flex-parent">
          <div class="child flex-child">
            <div class="grid-item item11">
              <div class="topnav">
                <input type="text" id="linkDirReq" class="input" maxlength="" value="" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off">
                  <span class="placeholder">Apples:</span><br/>
                  <span class="placeholder placeholder2">Search Apples:</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <div class="grid-item item12">
            <div class="child flex-child">
              <button id="linkDirReq_BT" type="submit" class="form-submit-button" tabindex="-1">SEARCH</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </span><br />

      <!-- /// -->

      <span class="fade-item">
        <div class="parent flex-parent">
          <div class="child flex-child">
            <div class="grid-item item13">
              <div class="topnav">
                <input type="text" id="linkDirEndPt" class="input" maxlength="" value="" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off">
                  <span class="placeholder">Avocatos:</span><br/>
                  <span class="placeholder placeholder2">Search Avocatos:</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <div class="grid-item item14">
            <div class="child flex-child">
              <button id="linkDirEndPt_BT" type="submit" class="form-submit-button" tabindex="-1">SEARCH</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </span><br />

      <!-- /// -->

    </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't know exactly which space was wanted and which was unwanted, so here's what I came up with. I removed the `&nbsp;` in there, since white space should be declared with margin/padding in CSS, not in HTML (which should describe structure).

I modified the CSS such that the outer "top-nav" class is set to `position: relative` and the inner "placeholder" classes is now `position: absolute`. This changes the calculation of `top`/`left`/`right` for the placeholders. I don't like repeating myself, so I made "placeholder2" override some key properties of "placeholder". This reduces the amount of CSS considerably.

Just a design note: I'm not sure about increasing the size of the inputs on focus; it can produce a rather odd motion effect where things are getting out of the way of others. But that's a judgement call; there's nothing inherently wrong with that.

Also, setting `outline` to 0 or `none` on focus is a bad practice for accessibility reasons. See for example [this article](https://dev.to/eevajonnapanula/dont-set-outline-0-or-outline-none-for-focus-styles-2olb).

```js
////////////////////////// - ANIMATE ITEMS ON LOAD - ////////////////////////

var items = document.querySelectorAll(".fade-item");
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
  fadeIn(items[i], i * 50)
}

function fadeIn(item, delay) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    item.classList.add('fadein')
  }, delay)
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(26, 26, 26);
  color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
  width: 290px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 1px rgb(78, 78, 78);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


/* ////////////////// ANIMATION ITEMS ONLOAD //////////////// */

.fade-item {
  transition: opacity transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

.fadein {
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 0.2s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0.3);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1.0);
  }
}


/* ////////////////// STRUCTURE //////////////////// */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .topnav a,
  .topnav input[type=text],
  .topnav .search-container button {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  .topnav input[type=text] {
    border: 1px solid rgb(102, 102, 102);
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

.top-nav {
  position: relative;
}

section {
  margin: 0 0 2rem;
}

/*////// BUTTON ///////*/

.form-submit-button {
  background: #464646;
  color: rgb(172, 172, 172);
  border-style: solid;
  height: 39px;
  width: 60px;
  font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 0px solid rgb(102, 102, 102);
  border-radius: 9px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease-out;
  animation: 0.25s ease-out 0s 1 scaleBtn;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scaleBtn {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
  }
}

.form-submit-button:hover {
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 5px #6461ff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 5px #6461ff;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}

.flex-parent:hover .form-submit-button {
  background: #5c5c5c;
}

.input:hover {
  background: #3d3d3d;
}

/*/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

/* Accessibility flag: this is a bad idea; many users depend on outline
   to see what button has the focus */
button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}


/*///////////// HIGHLIGHT BOX ANIMATION /////////////// */

.fade-item input[type="text"] {
  border: 2px solid rgb(238, 238, 238);
  background-color: rgb(49, 49, 49);
  height: 40px;
  -webkit-transition: all .4s;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0);
  /* will-change: transform, opacity; */
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  border-radius: 7px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.25s ease-out;
  animation: 0.25s ease-out 0s 1 scaleBtn;
}

@-webkit-keyframes scaleBtn {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.65);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.0);
  }
}

.fade-item input:focus {
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
  margin: 3px;
  scale: 103%;
  border-color: #e63f3f;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(233, 102, 102, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 8px rgba(233, 102, 102, 0.6);
}


/*///////////// PLACEHOLDER TEXT ANIMATION /////////////// */

.placeholder {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  top: 8px;
  left: 8px;
  font-family: Calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  color: grey;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 0);
  pointer-events: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: 1;
}

.input:focus~.placeholder {
  top: -55px;
  left: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #e4a8a8;
  opacity: 0;
}

.placeholder2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.input:focus~.placeholder2 {
  top: -12px;
  left: 8px;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(26, 26, 26);
  width: auto;
}

input:not(:focus) {
  top: -60px;
  right: -2px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: rgba(158, 89, 89, 0);
}


/*////////////////////// DIV ALIGNMENT SIDE BY SIDE ////////////////////////*/

.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-child {
  flex: 2 1 auto;
  display: flex;
}

.flex-child:last-child {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<h4>MY FRUITS</h4>
  <section>
    <div class="fade-item">
      <div class="parent flex-parent">
        <div class="child flex-child">
          <div class="topnav">
            <input type="text" id="linkBananas" class="input" maxlength="" value="" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off">
            <span class="placeholder">Search for bananas:</span>
            <span class="placeholder placeholder2">Insert banana number:</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="child flex-child">
          <button id="linkBananas_BT" type="submit" class="form-submit-button" tabindex="-1">SEARCH</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- /// -->

  <section>
    <div class="fade-item">
      <div class="parent flex-parent">
        <div class="child flex-child">
          <div class="topnav">
            <input type="text" id="linkApples" class="input" maxlength="" value="" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off">
            <span class="placeholder">Search for apples:</span>
    <!--<span class="placeholder placeholder2" >Enter apple number:</span> -->
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="child flex-child">
          <button id="linkApples_BT" type="submit" class="form-submit-button" tabindex="-1">SEARCH</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- /// -->

  <div class="fade-item">
    <div class="parent flex-parent">
      <div class="child flex-child">
        <div class="topnav">
          <input type="text" id="linkPeach" class="input" maxlength="" value="" autofocus="autofocus" autocomplete="off">
          <span class="placeholder">Search for peach:</span>
          <span class="placeholder placeholder2">Enter peach number:</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="child flex-child">
        <button id="linkPeach_BT" type="submit" class="form-submit-button" tabindex="-1">SEARCH</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi @Heretic Monkey I appreciate your reply and the time you took. I decided nevertheless to go with another option. I'm using ```display: inline-grid;``` and it seems to do the trick and more. I'll post an answer to my question with this in case you want to have a look. Your tips to shorten CSS and design are on the mark. I'm not too worried about the accessibility issues since this is for a limited number of users who won't have this kind of accessibility needs. Cheers